# Is there a way to test if there is a child attached to url of an image and compare it to hide image if there is no image

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to hide an ImageView when there is no Image (child is not present with url) (I use firebase as backend but I don't know how to compare values in my case I need to compare ""==childs value), here is a sample I am trying to do this with code but there is still Image placeholder:
Updated Post:Here is a pastebin of the Activity-  pastebin.com/3EgFdFsh

```
if (holder.post_image==null) {
            assert false;
            holder.post_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
        else{
            holder.post_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage())

                    .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder))
                    .into(holder.post_image);

        }
```

Look in my database:

[image: Picture]

```
if(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test").child("Posts").orderByChild("postimage").equals(""))query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                holder.post_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: That requires a Firebase query, with something like `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("postimage").equalTo("").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...`. Have a look at the Firebase documentation on [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) and [reading values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), and give it a try. If you get stuck, report back with the minimum, complete code that reproduces where you got stuck.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried this but nothing happens: (updated the post)

Comment: I think I messed up everything that if looks weird

Comment: I don't know how to make if statement with query can you help?

Comment: What does the code you added do? If you put a breakpoint inside `onDataChange` and run the code in a debugger, what value is in `dataSnapshot`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have no idea I found this lines of code laying around from other projects using queries and tried to clone them to my project, when I run this code there is no difference the else statement is just executed, btw I am kind of new to firebase and don't understand some stuff so it is better to point out few lines of code, I can send Pastebin I know that is like liching, I am noob I hope you can save my day ;)

Comment: Line 72 https://pastebin.com/3EgFdFsh

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the parameter singlesnapshot is grayed out I think it doesn't execute that line of code at all